# How to detect which block is closest to player? (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I am making a game simlar to [MotherLoad](http://www.xgenstudios.com/game.php?keyword=motherload). I'm trying to figure out how to mine downward. I've tried using OnCollisionStay and mining towards the block that the player is colliding with, but normally the player is on 2 blocks at once, so that isn't working.

Does anyone know a better method to do this?

Comment: You can compare distance between points pretty easily (subtract `posA` from `posB` and check the result's magnitude). If your game needs to check which object the player is "looking at", you could compare relative angles via dot products.

Comment: Yeah but I don't know how to get the other blocks position to compare.

Comment: Have you tried [raycasting](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)? Add colliders to the other blocks, raycast and see if it collides with something in front of the player. If there is a collision, you can reach its Transform component and then get the position of the other object, and then you can compare the positions to get the distance between them.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't messed with ray casting much so I didnt know what it was capable of. I'll read up on the documentation and see if it will solve my problem

Comment: 2D or 3D gameobject?